# how to show a fetch a string using javascript and display in html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, api, ipfs

**I have Uploaded a fully string data in IPFS:-
the URL is:- https://bafybeih3u62l664yz4ffpgrjci6ytl64rbivsgpovv6csty3j6kbx6natm.ipfs.infura-ipfs.io/
I put this URL in browser and it perfectly showing it,
is there any way, I can fetch this URL using JavaScript and show it to frontend like a image source attribute**

Comment: Please put your code snippet *in the question* not linked to some external site. Also, this question is too broad, try to focus it on some particular line or lines in your code

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
 fetch('https://bafybeih3u62l664yz4ffpgrjci6ytl64rbivsgpovv6csty3j6kbx6natm.ipfs.infura-ipfs.io/')
 .then(response => response.text())
 .then(data =>{
     document.getElementById('yourimg').src = data;
 });
```

Comment: Check it out here.  https://jsfiddle.net/vbuspn0q/